# Convert 32-bit compiled open source libraries to 64-bit compiled libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

In my project, I am having set of **open source libraries** that are **32-bit compiled**.
How to compile those libraries in a such a way that the libraries should be **64-bit compatible**?
How to make **64-bit compilation** for those open source libraries?

Comment: why not compile for 64bit first and ask a question when get errors?

Comment: I did it already and have got hundreds of errors. Most of them are like "referenced from" errors to the .o of particular libraries in the project. And am not sure, what kind of errors those are.

Comment: The libraries you linked should also be 64-bit compatible. It may have the warning "can't find slice for 64-bit ..."

Comment: "std::string::append(char const*)", referenced from somelib.o -- This is an example from hundreds of errors. Any inputs on this Dear KudoCC? Thank You in advance.

Comment: I suggest you upload a screenshot to show more details about the errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to convert library 32 bit to 64 bit.

Please  do follow step to resolve this issue.

1. You can find your open source library compatible with 64 bit on Web.
2. If didn't find library on web then you can build your lib with valid architecture with 64 bit. For the same set Library Target -> Build Setting -> Architecture.

Comment: Dear Jack, I can't find those libraries compatible with 64 bit on web and I tried even your second suggestion. Thanks...and I would like to request you for better guidance for me on sorting this problem out. Thank You!